# Getting different answers when using product rule and limit substitution than I do with quotient rule

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to differentiate $$y = \frac{x+1}{x-1}.$$

Using quotient rule:
http://prntscr.com/mt90yc

Using product:
http://prntscr.com/mt91dd

Using limit definition:
http://prntscr.com/mt91ih

I get $-2$ for product and limit, but I get $\frac{-2}{x^{2}-2x+1}$ using quotient.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Specifically, rather than using links to your prior work, it's considered a courtesy to your fellow contributors to place the work directly in the question.

Comment: I did not understand how did you apply the product rule. And the limit is missing some parentheses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you're doing something wrong.

$$
\left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)'=
\frac{(x+1)'(x-1)-(x+1)(x-1)'}{(x-1)^2}=\\
\frac{x-1-(x+1)}{(x-1)^2}=
\frac{x-1-x-1}{(x-1)^2}=-\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}
$$

---

$$
[(x+1)(x-1)^{-1}]'=\\
(x+1)'(x-1)^{-1}+(x+1)[(x-1)^{-1}]'=\\
(x-1)^{-1}+(x+1)(-1)(x-1)^{-2}=\\
\frac{1}{x-1}-\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^2}=
\frac{x-1}{(x-1)^2}-\frac{x+1}{(x-1)^2}=\\
\frac{x-1-x-1}{(x-1)^2}=-\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}
$$

---

$$
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{x+\Delta x+1}{x+\Delta x-1}-\frac{x+1}{x-1}}{\Delta x}=
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{\frac{(x+\Delta x+1)(x-1)-(x+1)(x+\Delta x-1)}{(x+\Delta x-1)(x-1)}}{\Delta x}=\\
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2-x+x\Delta x-\Delta x+x-1-(x^2+x\Delta x-x+x+\Delta x-1)}{\Delta x(x+\Delta x-1)(x-1)}=\\
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2+x\Delta x-\Delta x-1-(x^2+x\Delta x+\Delta x-1)}{\Delta x(x+\Delta x-1)(x-1)}=
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{x^2+x\Delta x-\Delta x-1-x^2-x\Delta x-\Delta x+1}{\Delta x(x+\Delta x-1)(x-1)}=\\
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{-2\Delta x}{\Delta x(x+\Delta x-1)(x-1)}=
\lim\limits_{\Delta x \rightarrow 0}\frac{-2}{(x+\Delta x-1)(x-1)}=\\
\frac{-2}{(x+0-1)(x-1)}=-\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}
$$

Comment: I see now, thanks.

Comment: Do you want me to do the limit example as well?

Comment: @Srijan Accept the answer, please. Thanks

Comment: @MichaelRybkin That would be useful as well, thanks.

Comment: @callculus Yup, just made an acc so I had a cool down.

Answer (score 1):

By the way, the simplest way to solve this problem is probably to observe

$$y= \frac{x+1}{x-1} = 1+\frac{2}{x-1} \Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{2}{(x-1)^2}.$$

I'm guessing the point of the problem was to convince yourself that the various techniques result in the same answer, but I didn't want you to overlook the value of simple division.

Comment: Yea, I did overlook that, thank you.

Comment: Thanks.  Feel free to upvote my answer if you found it useful.